# How to render multiple components in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to learn react and having problem with a small area. So this is my `App.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <h1>Heyy</h1>;
  }
  render(){
    return <h1>Helo</h1>
  }
}

export default App;
```

It only renders the `Helo`. If i have multiple components lets say `NavBar` and `ImageComp`, how would i render it on single page with before passing it to `ReactDOM.render`?

From what i understand, every components goes into `App` before going into `index.js` but then how would i include multiple components in App?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Component` MUST return either `JSX` or nothing `null`. Everything you need to render from a class based component should go inside `render` method:

```
class App extends Component{
    render(){
         return(
           <>
               <h1>Title</h1>
               <h2> Subtitle </h2>
               <MyCustomComponent />
           </>
        )
    }
}
```

The notation `<> </>` it's just a shortcut to `<React.Fragment />` to avoid returning adjacent `JSX` blocks

Comment: So does all my components go into one render method? and can you provide example with components rather than html?

Comment: Thank you! This has been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

React also permits you to return an Array of elements.

```
class App extends Component{
  render(){
     return[          
           <h1>Title</h1>,
           <h2> Subtitle </h2>,
           <MyCustomComponent />
     ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks ok, I'm newbie

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

var element = React.createElement
(
  'h1', 
  { className: 'greeting' }, 
  'Hello, world2!'
);

var buttonelem = React.createElement
(
  'button', 
  { className: 'button-class' }, 
  'Cicker'
);


ReactDOM.render([element,buttonelem], document.getElementById('root'));

reportWebVitals();
```